# error connecting to mongodb with mongoose on google compute engine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, network-programming, google-compute-engine

I'm following the [bookshelf app tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/run-on-compute-engine?hl=en). I was able to deploy the app and have my server running and connect it to my mongodb instance. Everything was working fine. When I tried to deploy my own app, I followed all the steps, I was able to get my code into the cloud repository. I started up a linux debian VM and supplied it the startup script I found in the tutorial but when I went to the address

```
http://<your-instance-ip>:8080
```

I WASN'T ABLE TO CONNECT TO MY APPLICATION. I SSHd into my instance and was able to navigate to the directory in which my file was saved, and I manually entered the command

```
node app.js
```

I immedietly got the console log that my application is running on port 8080. But after 10 minutes, I got an error that my application wasn't able to connect to the mongodb instance. I use mongoose to connect to mongodb whereas in the tutorial they used MongoClient. HERE IS MY CODE:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://***.***.***.***:27017/myappdatabase');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:')); 
db.once('open', function(callback) {
    console.log("connected to mongodb...");
});
```

and here is the tutorial code:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return cb(err);
  }
  collection = db.collection(collectionName);
  cb(null, collection);
});
```

WHERE url IS EXACTLY THE SAME AS THE URL IN MONGOOSE.CONNECT();

I'm pretty sure this is the only problem. When the VM spins up, it executes my app.js file and when it's not able to connect to mongodb, my server collapses.

Comment: 1) Do you need to specify a username and password to connect to your mongodb database? 2) If your mongodb is deployed on GCE instance, did you add GCE firewall rule to open tcp:27017 port?

Comment: you know what, that was it, thnx

Comment: @Rockstar5645 what was it?

Comment: @Kamran Hello. I'm having a similar issue.I have a node.js on app engine and I'm trying to use mongoose to connect to a MongoDb database hosted by mlab. When I run the node server locally on my laptop, I can connect just fine. When I run the same on my App Engine instance, I get the timeout error.

The mlab database is a sandbox database hosted on GCP, but not deployed on compute engine.

Comment: @Kamran The uri I'm connecting to with mongoose is of the form mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@xxxx.mlab.com:<portNumber>/db-name