# Connecting Mongoose on Google App Engine to mlab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine, mongoose, google-cloud-platform

I cannot connect to my mlab mongodb  for an application i deployed on gcp app engine.the application works fine when deployed to heroku  and localhost.I have checked on similar threads like [Connecting Mongoose on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527549/connecting-mongoose-on-google-app-engine) but still cant find my way around it.

```
(node:531) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to 
server[ds111422.mlab.com:11422] on firstconnect [MongoNetworkError: 
connection 0 to ds111422.mlab.com:11422 timed out] (node:531) [DEP0018] 
DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the 
future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js 
 process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have checked on googles documentation and can find any for mongoose connection there is just one for direct connection using plain nodejs.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly where the problem is but somehow when I read the the db connection details from a json file using nconf package as described by google https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-mongodb-on-appengine with no mongoose I was able to solve it.Initially i was reading from env variables.

```
`         nconf = require('nconf');
          const mongoose = require('mongoose');
          //key.json contains mongodb connection information
          nconf.argv().env().file('keys.json');
          const user = nconf.get('mongoUser');
          const pass = nconf.get('mongoPass');
          const host = nconf.get('mongoHost');
          const port = nconf.get('mongoPort')
          const mongoDatabase=nconf.get('mongoDatabase');
          let mongo_url=`mongodb://${user}:${pass}@${host}:${port}/${mongoDatabase}`;
          mongoose.connect(mongo_url,{useNewUrlParser: true});`
```